# how many records can be deleted using a single transaction in mysql innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I wanted to delete old records from 10 related tables every 6 months using primary keys and foreignkeys. I am planning to do it in a single transaction block, because in case of any failure I have to rollback the changes. My queries will be somethign like this

```
DELETE FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE PARENT_ID IN (1, 2, 3,etc);
DELETE FROM CHILD_TABLE1 WHERE PARENT_ID IN (1, 2, 3,etc);
```

The records to delete will be around 1million. Is it safe to delete all these in a single transaction? how will be the performanace?

---

**Edit**

To be more clear on my question. I will detail my execution plan

```
I am first retreiving primary keys of all the records from the parent table which has to be deleted and store it to a temporary table
START TRANSACITON
DELETE FROM CHILD_ONE WHERE PARENT_ID IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_ID_TABLE);
DELETE FROM CHILD_TWO WHERE PARENT_ID IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_ID_TABLE);
DELETE FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE PARENT_ID IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_ID_TABLE);
COMMIT;
```

ROLLBACK on any failure.

Given that I can have around a million records to delete from all these tables, is it safe to put everything inside a single transaction block?

Comment: You can delete every row in a single transaction if you wish, firstly I assume the table is innodb (otherwise transactions are meaningless), secondly if you have a date  / timestamp column, depending on your selectivity it *may* be simpler to select / delete where greater than (*however many months ago*) and lastly if you are using php and the delete does take a very long time you may need to adjust the maximum runtime parameters

Comment: Also if you are using foregn keys you can (and maye already have) set them to cascade on the deletion of the parent key so you would only need to write one delete query.

Comment: Yes @Lucas it is innodb tables and I cannot use casecade delete. My question was how many records I can safely delete under a single transaction box?

Comment: Your question is a little along the lines of "how long is a piece of string". Assuming there are no constraints on time/resources you should be fine to delete as many records as you feel you need to.

Comment: @Lucas I am not worried about how long the where condition can go. I will edit my question to be more specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably succeed.  But it is not wise.  Something random (eg, a network glitch) could come along to cause that huge transaction to abort.  You might be blocking other activity for a long time.  Etc.

Are the "old" records everything older than date X?  If so, it would *much* more efficient to make use of `PARTITIONing` for `DROPping` old rows.  We can discuss the details.  Oops, you have `FOREIGN KEYs`, which are incompatible with `PARTITIONing`.  Do all the tables have FKs?

Why do you wait 6 months before doing the delete?  6K rows a day would would have the same effect and be much less invasive and risky.

```
IN ( SELECT ... )
```

has terrible performance, use a `JOIN` instead.

If some of the tables are just normalizations, why bother deleting from them?

Would it work to delete 100 ids per transaction?  That would be much safer and less invasive.

Comment: Oh, "anything older than 6 months can be deleted"?  I read it as "I need to delete 6 months worth of data".  At 6 months + 1 day, you would have only one day's worth to delete?  This is much more manageable and efficient.  More tips in [my Delete blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Answer (score 2):

**First of all: Create a proper backup AND test it before you start to delete the records**

The number of record you asked for is mostly depends on the configuration (hardware) of your database server. You have to test it out, how many records could be deleted on that specific server without problems. Start with e.g. 1000 records then increase the amount in each iteration while it seems to be too slow. If you have replication, the setup and the slave's performance affects the row number too (too much write requests could cause serious delay in replication).

An advice: Remove all foreign keys and indexes (except the primary key and the indexes related to the where clauses you use to perform the action) if possible before you start the delete.

**Edit:**

If the count of records which will be deleted is larger than the count of records which will not, consider to just copy the records into a new table, then rename the old and new tables. For the first step, copy the structure of table using the `CREATE TABLE .. LIKE` statement, then drop all unnecessary indexes and constraints, copy the records, add the indexes, then rename the tables. (Copy the lastest new records from the original table into the copy if necessary), then you can drop the old table.

Comment: Thanks @Pred. Yes, i will do a check in the server. It is not possible for me to remove indexes. I will try to do in batches.

Answer (score 1):

what i believe first you have to move the data in another database then 
use single Transaction to delete all 10 table which is very safe to rollback immediately and delete the data from live data base when interaction of user is very less [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168486/whats-your-1-way-to-be-careful-with-a-live-database)

Comment: thanks @tinka I cannot move the data in another db, since it is a huge database, moving will take a lot of time and space. How many records can be deleted safely within a single transaction?